# RoR: Nested form and Patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for, fields-for

I have a form in my application with which I am looking to update fields in a column called "interest" using radio buttons which is in another model called "homework_students" so I am using (or trying!) a nested form:

```
    <%= form_for @homework, url: homework_homework_student_path(:homework_id => @homework, home_work_students_id => @homework_student,  :controller => 'homeworks', :action => 'update_interest'), method: :patch do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :homework_students do |builder| %>

  <%= builder.radio_button :interest, '1' %>
  </label>
  1
  <label>
    <%= builder.radio_button :interest, '2' %>
  </label>
  2
  <label>
    <%= builder.radio_button :interest, '3' %>
    3
  </label>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

In my models:

homework.rb:

```
has_many :homework_students, :class_name => 'HomeworkStudent', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :homework_students
```

homework_students.rb

```
belongs_to :homework, :class_name => 'Homework', :foreign_key => :homework_id, dependent: :destroy
```

The action I want to use in my controller (homeworks_controller.rb):

```
def update_interest
     @homework.homework_students.where(id: params[:home_work_students_id]).each do |homework_student| homework_student.update_attributes(:interest)
    end
    redirect_to @homework, notice: 'Homework was successfully updated.'
end
```

I am trying Patch here so in my routes:

```
resources :homeworks do
      member do
        patch :update_interest
      end
    resources :homework_students
  end
```

But it does not seem to use "update_interest" action. I don't have a homework_students controller either. I get this error, but probably more wrong with the above too.

```
undefined local variable or method `homework_student'
```

Thanks. Appreciate any guidance. Can give more info.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your model file name is not correct.(homework_students.rb)
It should be singular (homework_student.rb). Also your model class name will be singular.